# IntelliJ Ultimate + Tomcat does not open browser on run

Tags: intellij-idea, run-configuration

I **think**, first of all, its not an issue with configurations or other basic stuff (at least I think it is not) - I followed this tutorial: http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Creating_a_simple_Web_application_and_deploying_it_to_Tomcat

Basically everything works, except the "start browser" thing. If I click run, he starts tomcat, even debug is no problem, but:

**I have to manually point my browser to the page I want to view**

Its a little bit annoying, and I can't see why. I tried some workarounds (e.g. telling him not to use the "default browser", giving him the .exe path, disable all other browsers). Its not the end of the world, but the additional click in the JSP (on the little firefox icon on the top right) means I need the mouse, and thats not very comfortable - I rather just press a key and have a quick glance at the result, and switch back to the IDE to correct errors.

So anyone has had the same experience, is there some setting I am missing?

Chris

PS: I did the same with a JBOSS configuration a few days back, and there he starts the browser without a problem - maybe its my machine, will try on another machine tomorrow, to see if its a systematic problem.

I get these message, so the server starts up, maybe they changed the logging level and intellij is not "getting it" that the server is up an running:

```
Information: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Mrz 26, 2012 9:17:53 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Information: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mrz 26, 2012 9:17:53 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Information: Server startup in 556 ms
```

Comment: IntelliJ displays the start URL that I enter.  Maybe you aren't set up correctly.

Comment: Strange... Yeah, it must be something special, could not find the bug on the web (beside obvious stuff like checkmark not set on startup browser) - well will try in clean virtual machine, had some EAPs and community versions installed, maybe it screwed something up on my machine.

Answer (score 3):

You should see the following in the IntelliJ IDEA output panel:

```
INFO: Server startup in 141 ms
Connected to server
```

If you don't see these messages, the browser will not open. IDEA detects server start complete event from the logs. In case your application (or your server installation) customizes Tomcat  logging via its own logging configuration, IDEA may not be able to detect server start and will not open the browser.

Comment: Yeah, see them, server starts up fine. Tried to change port back to default (was using 8085), no effect. Clean install on other machine, same problem, browser just does not start up, everything else works. Maybe I do a workaround by starting the browser with a script, but lets wait a bit, can't see why I am the only one with this problem - so unfair :-)

Comment: Oh, and I dont get the last one, but in debugging he is able to stop at breakpoints, so he "kind of" is connected to the server (still does not start browser in debug)

Comment: So server connection is not detected for some reason. It's probably specific to the project as you said the Tomcat installation is vanilla.